# Adding two or more nested for loops in a JAVA programme

Tags: java, nested-loops

I am just a beginner in JAVA and while doing a class tutorial I got this problem. This is the output I should get:

```
  1    
 123
12345
 123
  1
```

I wrote this code and it gives a compilation error at line 16 saying that "for(int k=1; k<=5-i; k++)" is an unreachable statement.

```html
public class CaseThree{
 public static void main (String[] args){
  for(int a=1; a<=3; a++){
   for(int b=1; b<=3-a; b++){
    System.out.print(" ");
    }
   for(int c=1; c<=2*a-1; c++){
    System.out.print(c);
    }
   System.out.println();
   }
  for(int i=1; i<=2; i++){
   for(int j=1;; j++){
    System.out.print(" ");
    }
   for(int k=1; k<=5-2*i; k++){
    System.out.print(k);
   }
   System.out.println();
  }
 }
}
```

What is wrong with this code? (Our lecturer told us to use two separate nested for loops.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the code right before the statement that the compiler says that is impossible to reach

```
for(int j=1;; j++){
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

the validation expression is empty, hence this is an infinite loop which explain the compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

for (int j = 1;\WHAT GOES HERE?\; j++)

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loop at line 13. No conditional check to end loop.. And you dont need that many for loops for that kind of output.